# File download with call back asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use following code to download file from server

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{            
    string path = "get path of file";
    return this.File(path, "content-type", "download-file-name");
}
```

Now i want to know is there any method to know either file is downloaded on client side, i.e server has transferred all bytes. So that I can make a callback function on server for this event.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a custom action filter:

```
 public class FileDownloadCompletedFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
 {         
      public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
      {
           //  file download complete  
      }
 }
```

then decorate your action with this filter:

```
[FileDownloadCompleted]
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{            
    string path = "get path of file";
    return this.File(path, "content-type", "download-file-name");
}
```